# ruby abbreviated dates - how to order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create an array of shortened date names, so something like this...

```
@months = ['apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep','oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar']
```

However, I would rather do it programatically, like this

```
@months = I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names").compact
```

the problem is that the latter begins with 'jan', and I need to be able to specify the starting month, as with the first one. The starting month gets changed every few months so eventually I will have to pass it in..

any ideas, or is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [rotate](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate) for this:

```
I18n.t("date.abbr_month_names").compact.rotate(3) 
# output => ['apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep','oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'jan', 'feb', 'mar']
```